# Accessing contents of NativeWindow in a HTML AIR application?

Tags: javascript, html, air, nativewindow

I'm currently building a HTML/JS AIR application. The application needs to display to the user a different 'window' - dependant on whether this is the first time they've launched the application or not. This part is actually fine and I have the code below to do that:

```
if(!startUp()) { // this simply returns a boolean from a local preferences database that gets shipped with the .air
        // do first time stuff
        var windowOptions = new air.NativeWindowInitOptions();
            windowOptions.systemChrome = 'none';
            windowOptions.type = 'lightweight';
            windowOptions.transparent = 'true';
            windowOptions.resizable = 'false';
        var windowBounds = new air.Rectangle(300, 300, 596, 490);
        var newHtmlLoader = air.HTMLLoader.createRootWindow(true, windowOptions, true, windowBounds);
            newHtmlLoader.load(new air.URLRequest('cover.html'));
}
else {
    // display default window
    // just set nativeWindow.visible = true (loaded from application.xml)
}
```

However, what I want to be able to do is *manipulate* the html content from within `cover.html` after it has loaded up. There seems to be plenty of tutorials online of how to move, resize, etc. the `NativeWindow`, but I simply want access to the `NativeWindow`'s HTML content.

For example, how would I add a new paragraph to that page? I've tried the following:

```
newHtmlLoader.window.opener = window;               
var doc = newHtmlLoader.window.opener.document.documentElement;
```

Using AIR's Introspector console, ...`.log(doc)` returns `[object HTMLHtmlElement]`.

Hmm, seems promising right? I then go on to try:

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
var t = document.createTextNode('Insert Me');
p.appendChild(t);
doc.appendChild(p);
```

...but nothing gets inserted. I've also tried the following replacements for `doc`:

```
var doc = newHtmlLoader.window.opener.document.body; // .log(doc) -> [object HTMLBodyElement]
var doc = newHtmlLoader.window.opener.document; // .log(doc) -> Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3
```

...as well as the following with jQuery:

```
$(doc).append('<p>Insert Me</p>'); // again, nothing
```

So, anyone had any experience in accessing a `NativeWindow`'s inner content programmatically? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, so I think I may have found out how to do it...If we amend the original code and add an event listener on the loader:

```
var newHtmlLoader = air.HTMLLoader.createRootWindow(true, windowOptions, true, windowBounds);
newHtmlLoader.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE, doEventComplete);
newHtmlLoader.load(new air.URLRequest('cover.html'));
```

You can then interact (assuming you're using jQuery) with the contents of the newly created window by using:

```
function doEventComplete(event) {
    doc = $(event.currentTarget.window.document.body);
    doc.append('<p>Insert Me!</p>')
}
```

:)

Comment: Perfect, solved my problem! Thanks :) Not very clear at all how to pass data between two windows in an air app...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this has the effect you intended:

```
newHtmlLoader.window.opener = window;               
var doc = newHtmlLoader.window.opener.document.documentElement;
```

What is does is set `var doc = window.document.documentElement;`, so 'doc' is your local document, not the one in the other window.

I think what you want is

```
var doc = newHtmlLoader.window.document.documentElement;
```

Do note that this will not work until the document has loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jakob. I tried out what you've said but unfortunately still nothing.

I called a function using setTimeout() after 5 seconds to attempt to insert the paragraph but that didn't work either, so it doesn't seem to be an issue of the document not being loaded.